# UILabel TextAlignement Vertical Top

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uilabel

I have a great problem, I have a `UILabel` created programmatically and then connect via Interface builder, where i have positionated where I need, but i see that the text i set in it it's printed in the center of the `UILabelBox`, I have found a lot of question but i haven't know I can use it, I have found this:

```
//
//  VerticallyAlignedLabel.h
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef enum VerticalAlignment {
    VerticalAlignmentTop,
    VerticalAlignmentMiddle,
    VerticalAlignmentBottom,
} VerticalAlignment;

@interface VerticallyAlignedLabel : UILabel {
@private
    VerticalAlignment verticalAlignment_;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) VerticalAlignment verticalAlignment;

@end

//
//  VerticallyAlignedLabel.m
//

#import "VerticallyAlignedLabel.h"


@implementation VerticallyAlignedLabel

@synthesize verticalAlignment = verticalAlignment_;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        self.verticalAlignment = VerticalAlignmentMiddle;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setVerticalAlignment:(VerticalAlignment)verticalAlignment {
    verticalAlignment_ = verticalAlignment;
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (CGRect)textRectForBounds:(CGRect)bounds limitedToNumberOfLines:(NSInteger)numberOfLines {
    CGRect textRect = [super textRectForBounds:bounds limitedToNumberOfLines:numberOfLines];
    switch (self.verticalAlignment) {
        case VerticalAlignmentTop:
            textRect.origin.y = bounds.origin.y;
            break;
        case VerticalAlignmentBottom:
            textRect.origin.y = bounds.origin.y + bounds.size.height - textRect.size.height;
            break;
        case VerticalAlignmentMiddle:
            // Fall through.
        default:
            textRect.origin.y = bounds.origin.y + (bounds.size.height - textRect.size.height) / 2.0;
    }
    return textRect;
}

-(void)drawTextInRect:(CGRect)requestedRect {
    CGRect actualRect = [self textRectForBounds:requestedRect limitedToNumberOfLines:self.numberOfLines];
    [super drawTextInRect:actualRect];
}

@end
```

Anyone can help me how I can use it please?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I know it may be late to answer, but I did it this way:

I made a Category for UILabel and call `-setVerticalAlignmentTop` when it was needed.

```
// UILabel(VAlign).h
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface UILabel (VAlign)
- (void) setVerticalAlignmentTop;
@end

// UILabel(VAlign).m
#import "UILabel(VAlign).h"
@implementation UILabel (VAlign)
- (void) setVerticalAlignmentTop
{
    CGSize textSize = [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font
                            constrainedToSize:self.frame.size
                                lineBreakMode:self.lineBreakMode];

    CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x,
                                 self.frame.origin.y,
                                 self.frame.size.width,
                                 textSize.height);
    [self setFrame:textRect];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

@end
```

Comment: Just in case anyone uses this and finds that it doesn't work: The UILabel's text has to be set BEFORE you set the alignment, else the calculation will be made on no text. Just saying :-)

Comment: Thanks, Muncken. That worked :P I think that's enough coding for tonight!

Comment: Your solution worked great for me as well. And I'd like to add, the more I use categories, the more I love them!

Comment: without calling a new method, can't it be done as automatic for all the labels?

Comment: I think it is not possible. You are not allowed to override existence methods in category. It will be done by subclassing.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it as follows.......

1. Set your label's `numberOfLines` property 0 from IB
2. Set your label's `lineBreakMode` as `UILineBreakModeWordWrap` (very very important)

now whatever you set on the label just append few @"\n" to it.....
ex.-

```
[yourTextLabel setText:@"myLabel\n\n\n\n\n"];
```

Comment: This problem nearly drove me crazy until find your solution! Thanks! Anyway Apple should implement a feature to align labels...